# determining selection made using alert dialog (radio Buttons)

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a popup I want to create that will have 3 choices. (Block, Unblock, Uninstall).  Below I have a Confirm|Cancel button.  I would like to see which button is pressed, and based on that will display a toast corresponding to the selection.  I have written some code to show what I am trying to do.  Obviously the if items[item] == Block won't work, but in a simplified sense that is what I am trying to do.  Can someone show me how I would write the OnClickListener to capture what button was clicked and how to differenciate it when clicking Confirm?

Code:

```
package com.popup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class PopupActivity extends Activity { 


    String TAG = "PopUpActivity";
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        BlockUnblockUninstallPopUp("");
        String TAG = "PopUpActivity";
    }
    public void BlockUnblockUninstallPopUp(final String PackageName){       
        //Items you would like to list as options.
         final CharSequence[] items = {"Block", "UnBlock", "Uninstall"};
         String flag = null;
          AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(PopupActivity.this);

        //Title of Popup
          builder.setTitle("What would you like to do?"); 

          builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        //When you click the radio button
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

              } 
          }); 

        //When you click Confirm
          builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm", 
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                  if(items[item] == "Block") 
                  {
                Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this,PackageName + " Blocked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG,PackageName + " Blocked.");
                  }
                  if(items[item] == "Unblock") 
                  {
                Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this,PackageName + " Unblocked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  Log.d(TAG,PackageName + " Unblocked.");  
                  }
                  if(items[item] == "Uninstall") 
                  {
                  Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this,PackageName + " Uninstalled.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                Log.d(TAG,PackageName + " Uninstalled.");
                  }
            } 
           }); 
        //When you click Cancel, Leaves PopUp.
          builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", 
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) { 
            } 
           }); 
        //Creates the AlertDialog  
          AlertDialog alert = builder.create(); 

        //Starts the Popup.
          alert.show(); 


      } 

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  int i;
  builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, -1,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        // When you click the radio button
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item)                   {

                                i=item;
                        }
                    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                        if (items[i] == "Block") {
                            Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this,
                                    PackageName + " Blocked.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, PackageName + " Blocked.");
                        }
                        if (items[i] == "UnBlock") {
                            Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this,
                                    PackageName + " Unblocked.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, PackageName + " Unblocked.");
                        }
                        if (items[i] == "Uninstall") {
                            Toast.makeText(PopupActivity.this,
                                    PackageName + " Uninstalled.",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Log.d(TAG, PackageName + " Uninstalled.");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Comment: That seems like it should work.  I am having a problem (probably a stupid question). It says I need to make it 

Final int i; but then I get:

Multiple markers at this line
 - The final local variable i cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing 
  type
 - Cannot refer to a non-final variable i inside an inner class defined in a different 
  method

Comment: So there is no way to obtain the selected radio button directly in the positive button listener, without setting up an extra listener in the build to set an arbitrary variable to the selected item?